# Error while running collect() action in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

While practising Apache Spark using Python, I am getting error while running collect() command.
I am trying the below code in Jupyter notebook.

```
vehicledata = sc.textFile("/home/newuser/Desktop/vehicle_data.csv")
vehicledata.collect()

[u'suzuki,gas,std,two,hatchback,fwd,four,69,4900,31,36,5118',
 u'volvo,gas,std,two,hatchback,fwd,four,75,5400,37,40,3700',
 u'chevrolet,gas,std,two,sedan,fwd,four,65,5600,30,32,4800',
 u'toyota,gas,std,two,sedan,fwd,four,45,7800,45,47,3900',
 u'tata,gas,std,two,hatchback,fwd,four,40,5900,50,52,7800',
 u'tata,gas,std,four,hatchback,fwd,four,20,3100,30,35,2355',
 u'suzuki,gas,std,four,hatchback,fwd,four,20,2500,28,30,6355',
 u'chevrolet,gas,std,two,sedan,fwd,four,47,4900,23,27,2300',
 u'hyundai,cell,std,two,SUV,fwd,four,55,6500,20,25,7000',
 u'benz,gas,std,two,SUV,fwd,four,60,7300,26,30,7900',
 u'']
```

Here I am taking two values by splitting vehicle brand and eighth field value.

```
cyldata = vehicledata.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[0], x.split(",")[7]))
cyldata.collect()
```

When I run the above collect() command I am getting the following error.
Since I am new for Spark, I could not able to make out the error.

Can I know is there any mistake done in coding or error due to improper spark anaconda installation.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-795ae9e596f7> in <module>()
----> 1 cyldata.collect()

/home/newuser/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in collect(self)
    771         """
    772         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 773             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    774         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    775 

/home/newuser/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/newuser/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     34     def deco(*a, **kw):
     35         try:
---> 36             return f(*a, **kw)
     37         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     38             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/home/newuser/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/newuser/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/home/newuser/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/newuser/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-8-1adc0c950e09>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1921)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:908)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/newuser/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/home/newuser/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/newuser/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-8-1adc0c950e09>", line 1, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue isn't specific to Spark at all.

First look at the Specific error message thrown: list Index out of range.
Now look at the last line of your data -- its empty. Which means splitting it by ',' will give you empty result.

Answer (score 0):

you want 1st and 8th element from line which is not present in last line.
clean your data before load .

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the accepted answer, does it?